# How to query my data based on multiple criteria in the most efficient way in REDIS?

Tags: php, redis, key-value, key-value-store

I'm not used to working with key-value stores.

I'm creating a web game. My goal is to match online users with each other. Once the user is online and decides to play, they will be added to the REDIS datastore temporarily (until they log off).

I will add them using their ID as key and their details (NAME, GAMETOPLAY, RANKING, STATUS, ...etc) in either a hash or a set. Not sure which is the better datatype yet.

**How do I match users (i.e. REDIS records) together?** Basically I will have pending users in the REDIS datastore and I want to go through each record until I get a match. But apparently you cannot search in REDIS, so how do I accomplish this?

I don't want to pull out each record from redis just to check it's details. That seems very expensive resource wise. There must be a better way.

EDIT:

To be more precise. I want to query my data based on multiple criteria. Apparently you can do that using sorted sets. But I still need multiple criteria. Some criteria, I can get away with by storing in a different table/database (?) I guess but not all.

EDIT 2:

Apparently I can accomplish this using multidimensional indexes.

Comment: It seems what's you want is `mongodb` or `mysql`

Answer (score 1):

The REDIS way of doing searches is first to create and maintain indexes for your queries.

Lets say, that you are adding new user with RANKING X, GAMETOPLAY Y, and you will be searching for users by ranking range and gametoplay exact value.

Your task now is to create structure which will have those those users for you, like sorted set "gametoplay:*gametoplayvalue*" (keys = user_id, and scores = Ranking)

Other solution of multiple search criteria would be to use:

http://redis.io/commands/sinter

http://redis.io/commands/sinterstore

You maintain sets, like:

- status_set:status (key = user_id)
- gametoplay_set:game_id (key = user_id)
- ranking:ranking_from_x_to_y (key = user_id)

And when you want to find users by multiple criteria you can use sinter to get intersection.

To sum it up:

- when adding user, add his ID to all needed sets/hashes
- then just query those sets/hashes for ids
- when removing user, remove his ID from all sets/hashes

Answer (score 0):

You may store the temporary details of the user by prepending some prefix to the id.

tmp_(user_id)

prepend tmp_ to the user_id for temporary details.

and simply user_id for permanent details